# how to view kafka headers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are sending message with headers to Kafka using 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

```
public ProducerRecord(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V value, Iterable<Header> headers) {
    this(topic, partition, (Long)null, key, value, headers);
}
```

How can I actually see these headers using command. kafka-console-consumer.sh only shows me payload and no headers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the excellent [kafkacat](https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html) tool.

Sample command:

```
kafkacat -b kafka-broker:9092 -t my_topic_name -C \
  -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k
  Value (%S bytes): %s
  Timestamp: %T
  Partition: %p
  Offset: %o
  Headers: %h\n'
```

Sample output:

```
Key (-1 bytes):
  Value (13 bytes): {foo:"bar 5"}
  Timestamp: 1548350164096
  Partition: 0
  Offset: 34
  Headers: __connect.errors.topic=test_topic_json,__connect.errors.partition=0,__connect.errors.offset=94,__connect.errors.connector.name=file_sink_03,__connect.errors.task.id=0,__connect.errors.stage=VALU
E_CONVERTER,__connect.errors.class.name=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter,__connect.errors.exception.class.name=org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException,__connect.errors.exception.message=Co
nverting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: ,__connect.errors.exception.stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed
 due to serialization error:
```

The kafkacat header option is only available in recent builds of `kafkacat`; you may want to [build](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/173) from master branch yourself if your current version doesn't include it.

---

You can also run kafkacat from Docker:

```
docker run --rm edenhill/kafkacat:1.5.0 \
      -b kafka-broker:9092 \
      -t my_topic_name -C \
      -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k
  Value (%S bytes): %s
  Timestamp: %T
  Partition: %p
  Offset: %o
  Headers: %h\n'
```

If you use Docker bear in mind the network implications of how to reach the Kafka broker.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: does it work with kafka 2.3.0? my kafkacat is 1.3.1 and it returns 
`% ERROR: Unsupported formatter: %h`

Comment: Works fine against AK 2.3. I'm using kafkacat `Version 1.3.1-52-gc7986d (JSON) (librdkafka 1.0.0 builtin.features=gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins)`. Did you try the build from master?

Comment: besides being a great tool (thanks @RobinMoffatt!), another good thing about it is it's available to install via apt-get and brew.

Answer (score 38):

Starting with kafka-2.7.0 you can enable printing headers in console-consumer by providing property `print.headers=true`

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic quickstart-events --property print.key=true --property print.headers=true --property print.timestamp=true`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [kafkactl](https://github.com/deviceinsight/kafkactl) for this. E.g. with output as yaml:

```
kafkactl consume my-topic --print-headers -o yaml
```

Sample output:

```
partition: 1
offset: 22
headers:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
value: my-value
```

Disclaimer: I am contributor to this project

Comment: kafkactl easy install on Centos 7, easy usage, thank you

Answer (score 7):

From `kafka-console-consumer.sh` script:

```
exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer "$@"
```

src: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.1/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh

In `kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer` the header is provided to the Formatter, but none of the existing Formatters makes use of it:

```
formatter.writeTo(new ConsumerRecord(msg.topic, msg.partition, msg.offset, msg.timestamp,
                                     msg.timestampType, 0, 0, 0, msg.key, msg.value, msg.headers),
                                     output)
```

src: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala

At the bottom of the above link you can see existing Formatters.

If you want to print headers you need to implement your own `kafka.common.MessageFormatter` and in particular its write method:

```
def writeTo(consumerRecord: ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]], output: PrintStream): Unit
```

and then run your console consumer with --formatter providing your own formatter (it should also be present on the classpath).

Another, simpler and faster way, would be to implement your own mini-program using KafkaConsumer and check headers in debug.

Answer (score 2):

```
kcat -C -b $brokers -t $topic -f 'key: %k Headers: %h: Message value: %s\n'
```

Comment: What is `kcat`, could you provide some pointer?

Comment: DOH! https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tools/kafkacat-usage.html